# Ionic ex is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, reference, ionic-framework

I'm currently using the ionic framework to create a application. But I suddenly currently am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: ex is not defined
at Lexer.peek (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21323:22)
at Lexer.lex (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21290:72)
at Object.AST.ast (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21473:30)
at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21927:31)
at Parser.parse (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22776:29)
at $parse (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22900:39)
at $interpolate (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19639:25)
at addAttrInterpolateDirective (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17318:27)
at collectDirectives (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16455:13)
at compileNodes (http://localhost:7000/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16282:22) <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="ios">
```

I have no clue what could be causing this. Any help would be gladly apreciated!

Comment: Is _ex_ an external library?

Comment: It looks like it's failing to interpolate one of your expressions, maybe you can share the expression that has **ex** in it, and some of it's context?